# Install ubuntu and still have windows installer?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows, iso

I have a 64gb USB stick that I want to use for ubuntu (full install) but I also want to be able to install windows when I need to. I'm currently using ventoy to dual boot iso's but the lack of persistence (and the 4gb limit when you do have persistence in some iso's) is not usable for me.
So to summarize, I want to install ubuntu to a usb stick, but I want to have a windows installer on there too so I can install windows on a pc when I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use another USB flash drive.

You can't install Ubuntu or put Ubuntu installation media on the same flash drive as Windows installation media.

Comment: Okay! By the way, is the process of updating ubuntu on usb (or just in general) hard? I've never actually used ubuntu before (or any linux distro)

Comment: If you install Ubuntu to a USB, it will work just like Ubuntu installed to any other drive.

Comment: Do I need a second usb stick to install ubuntu to the 64gb usb stick?

Comment: Yes. The Ubuntu installation media needs to run from somewhere. Generally that's from a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another partition on the 64 GB USB stick for your `Windows.iso` and `Ubuntu.iso` (or only your `Windows.iso`). And another one to install your `Ubuntu` on. 
What I never tried though is installing `Ubuntu` from that first partition to the second one. So I don't know if that would work. But you can try it. Normal is that when you install ubuntu the installation files are loaded into memory. 
The easiest way though is using 1 stick for the `iso` and 1 stick (the 64 GB) to install `Ubuntu` to/on.